# Basic comments formatting in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I am playing with [Orchard CMS](http://orchard.codeplex.com/). The problem is that comments are formatted as plain text and even `<p>` tags are not generated.

How to make possible a basic formatting such as `<p>` or may be `<b>`, `<i>`?

Answer (score 5):

You override the view ListOfComments.cshtml within your own theme, then you can change what is output to the ui.

Orchard allows you to override any view/shape within your theme, hence allowing you to basically do whatever you like.